# Rendering Raphael elements upon paper with opacity

Tags: css, raphael

I am using Raphael 2.1.0 ([raphaeljs.com](http://raphaeljs.com/)) with no problem. Actually I'm drawing elements upon a `<div>` with `opacity: 0.6;`. It is obvious that the Raphael elements get the same opacity.

I was wondering if there was any way to render opaque elements (100%) upon a transparent paper (60%).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AFTQV/4/) is a JSFiddle to illustrate my thing.

What I thought at first was putting a layer without background right above my transparent `<div>`, which would be my paper. That way, it could give its opacity (100%) to my Raphael elements.

But I'm thinking I am  missing an easier way.

Comment: Instead of `opacity: 0.6` and a background color, try using `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

Comment: Thanks, it does work well. But since it's CSS3 (I think), it won't work before IE9. Do you have any workaround ?

Comment: You can use this Gradient generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and it will work in IE7-9 too. [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFTQV/5/)

Comment: It doesn't look alike though. Thanks anyway, I guess I could always warn the user he's using a crappy browser. If I don't get another solution feel free to answer, formally.

Comment: Older versions of browsers are a pain! :) But in terms of Progressive Enhancement, you could serve up a normal background colour, ie `background-color:#fff` above the rgba rule, and older browser will render the full white colour, and modern browsers would render the rgba rule.

Comment: Yeah, that is how I handled my opacity issues in my previous projects. However, this time is different: I have a video player on which the user is able to draw polygons with the mouse (the paper is right above the player and they both have the same size). I found handy to make the drawing overlay a bit transparent, but having it with full opacity would be no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your fiddle, I can see that you have an outer `div` called `#overlay` and a `div` inside that called `#paper`. You are rendering your paper inside `#paper` and applying `background:white; opacity:0.6;` style to `#paper` itself.

As mentioned in comments in your question, using `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);` instead of `opacity` is an option. But that will not work IE 8 and below and alos on some older versions of other browsers.

A much more semantic way to do it would be to insert a new `div` with same height as the `#paper` before `#paper` and then apply a negative margin to `#paper` to bring it above the newly inserted `div`.

```
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="paperbg"></div>
  <div id="paper"></div>
</div>
```

And your CSS would go like

```
#overlay {
  background: #88bb00;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

#paper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -400px;
}

#paperbg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shamasis/AFTQV/8/

Comment: Thanks, that's basically the way I thought of at first (see original question). Since the solution provided in the comments doesn't render the exact same colors, I guess I'll go this way.

Comment: Great. :) It would be cross-browser too. Just don't forget to add the vendor specific CSS prefixes for your opacity rule. `-moz-opacity`, `-khtml-opacity`, etc. :)